# SQL Server 2008 Export wizard unable to parse a query with While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a T-Sql query in SQL Server 2008. It works properly in SQL server but when i try to use the same query in Export Wizard, it throws an error message saying the query is Invalid. If i remove the while statement from the query it gets parsed. Can you help me executing my query using while?

Here is the Query

```
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime
declare @start_time datetime
declare @end_time datetime
declare @table_time_breakup table([Start DateTime] datetime, [End DateTime] datetime)

set @start_date='20131201'
set @end_date='20140101'
set @start_time = @start_date
set @end_time=dateadd(hh, 1, @start_time)

while @end_time <= @end_date
Begin 
    insert into @table_time_breakup
    select @start_time, @end_time
    set @start_time=@end_time
    set @end_time=dateadd(hh, 1, @start_time)
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `while` loop with recursive `CTE` like this:

```
;with [base] as
(
    select @start_time [start_time], dateadd(hh, 1, @start_time) [end_time]
    union all
    select [end_time], dateadd(hh, 1, [end_time])
    from [base]
    where dateadd(hh, 1, [end_time]) < @end_date
)
select * from [base] option (maxrecursion 0)
```

And btw I think you do not need to use `INSERT` statement inside Export Wizard... it only asks you for `SELECT` statement to fetch data from the data source

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add at the end...

```
select [Start DateTime], [End DateTime] from @table_time_breakup
```

The export is just looking to make sure you have a select statement.